# How to store "user-made" objects in python correctly?

Tags: python, object, input, persistence, shelve

I have a case in which the program accepts an imput from his user, and then creates some input-based objects.

```py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def dogmaker():
    name = input()
    dog = Dog(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dogmaker()
```

This should create an instance of the Dog() class with a dog object with name chosen by the user.

How can I use shelves/pickle to have the user-made object stored somewhere and have them on next run of my program?

Which one is better to use between pickle and shelves and what is the difference?

Comment: you forgot `()` in `buster.bark()`

Comment: you have to put `def bark(self)` inside `class` to use `buster.bark()` . And indentions are important.

Comment: if you need instance with values when you run next time then you have to save it in file. You can create own method to save data in text file, and second method to read data from file. You can also use modules  like `pickle` to save/read instance. In both situatioms you will have to read it at start, and save it at the end of program.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I wrote this little code here just to make my example. I knew there were a lot of errors in it! For full problem check my other question, i give a long and detailed explanation here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194923/how-to-add-persistence-to-multiple-user-made-objects-in-my-program-with-pickle

Answer (score 0):

you can use pickle to save almost any python data type to disk:

```
import pickle
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# save dogs to file
def save_dogs(dog_list):
    with open('myfile', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dog_list, f)

# load dogs from file
def load_dogs():
    with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f) 

dog1 = Dog('shewawa')
dog2 = Dog('Bulldog')

# make a list that holds your dogs
dogs = [dog1, dog2]

save_dogs(dogs) 
mydogs = load_dogs()

# you have a loaded list of dogs and can iterate over or say dog1 = dogs[0] and so on
for dog in mydogs:
    print(dog.name)
```

output:

```
shewawa
Bulldog
```

Comment: I almost did it, and I can make it work for a single dog. But when my class has multiple instances? How can load them all in a single time? I managed to save them succesfully, but my load is not working!

Comment: you can make a list and append dogs to this list then pickle this list, i will try to edit my answer

Comment: Ok but I see you manually create the two dog instances. If I want a user to put some input, create dogs named after input, save them and then retrieve them is the process the same? I'll link you another question of mine containing full information and code about my issue. Thank you very much, you are very kind helping me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194923/how-to-add-persistence-to-multiple-user-made-objects-in-my-program-with-pickle